# Can foundation be used in BigCartel?

Tags: css, e-commerce, zurb-foundation, bigcartel

I'm trying to customize my Big Cartel ecommerce and I want it to be responsive. The problem is that I only know foundation as responsive framework and I don't know how to import it.

I've tried to copy all the source code, but i'm unable to save because the editor says it's too long and I haven't found any online resource where i can just link like it's usually done with jquery.

I'll be glad if someone can give me a way to include foundation or if it's not possible, other responsive framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Foundation (or any other framework) with Big Cartel, but unfortunately copying/pasting the entire source code into your Big Cartel theme isn't really possible due to the content editor limit you mentioned. So instead you'll need to have the files hosted on a separate webserver, or a service like Dropbox - like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webserver.com/css/foundation.css">
<!-- This is how you would link your custom stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webserver.com/css/app.css">
<script src="http://webserver.com/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="http://webserver.com/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://webserver.com/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

You'll just need to make sure that there aren't any javascript conflicts (like jQuery already being loaded in your existing theme, for example) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, I hosted my files in google drive and the speed, that I was concerned about, is absolutelly ok.